# Duvidas com conversão de variaveis

Tags: javascript, html, conversão-de-tipo

Estou fazendo um jogo de criança que testa seus conhecimentos matemáticos. Basicamente o jogo é o seguinte:

A página de entrada tem uma serie de casas interligadas, onde cada casa tem seu próprio valor numérico.

A princípio a criança vai clicar na primeira casa que gera um evento que chama uma função que registra o numero da casa e o valor da casa. Essa mesma função gera um alert convidando a criança apertar o botão jogar dados. Esse botão chama uma função que gera dois números aleatórios e apresenta os mesmos na tela e apresenta uma mensagem orientando a criança a somar os dois valores e digitá-los num form.  Ao mesmo tempo que a criança faz a soma, uma função pega os mesmos valores e  e procede a soma, conta um tempo e compara os resultados, se estiver igual um alert parabeniza e orienta a seguir em frente, caso contrario ele será informado que a conta esta errada e que deve faze-la novamente. Estando certo ela é parabenizada e convidada a dividir o resultado da soma efetuada pelo valor da casa onde ela esta ( no caso aqui 1ª casa). O valor do resto desta divisão (modulo) será o numero de casas que ela deve avançar. Supondo que tenha sobrado 5, a criança será convidada a avançar o numero correspondente a sobra da divisão efetuada por ela. O programa fará a contagem da casas e comparará com a casa escolhida, se forem iguais o a criança será parabenizada e convidada a apertar o botão jogar os dados novamente e todo processo se repetirá até que chegue a casa fim de jogo. Se a casa escolhida não corresponder ao resultado esperado, a conta realizada pela criança estará errada e ela será informada e orientada a efetua-la novamente.

Tenho dois problemas. Não consigo pegar os valores gerados aleatóriamente, coloca-los numa variável, para comparar posteriormente. Pelo código que fiz ele ta gerando NaN, já tentei de tudo para fazer a conversão e nada. O código segue abaixo.

O outro problema é como fazer a contagem das casas pelo valor gerado pelo resto da divisão, de forma que se uma casa qualquer escolhida não corresponder a contagem correta de um erro. Desculpe o texto é longo mas procurei expressar o que estou tentando fazer. Mas deixe me ser mais explicito neste segundo problema relatado na pergunta.
Nesse jogo eu tenho que percorrer uma serie de tabelas sendo que cada uma tem seu numero e um valor. Tipo tabela 1 valor 30, tabela 2 valor 15, tabela 3 valor 17.
Com um clic o aluno inicia pela tabela 1. O valor desta tabela será dividido valor da soma do sorteio. O resto dessa divisão (modulo) será o numero de tabelas que o usuário irá percorrer, ou seja, se o resto 5, significará que o usuário deverá percorrer apenas cinco tabelas e clicar na quinta.
Até aqui tudo bem, mas o programa deve reconhecer que o usuário fez a conta certa, mediante a contagem que ele fez, ou seja, se ele escolher a casa que não corresponda ao resto da divisão, um alerta devera surgir avisando que ele deve refazer a conta. Estou postando aqui o script HTML com as tabelas que foram criadas, esse script é só parte, pois são mais de trinta tabelas, mas já da para ter uma idéia.
Posto também função. Preciso desenvolver uma função que reconheça e pegue o valor da tabela que o usuário está, e divida pelo valor da variável numérica resultante do sorteio, e quando o usuário que fez essa conta também, fizer a contagem das tabelas de acordo com resto de sua conta, e clicar na tabela, se estiver errado, o programa devera reconhecer o erro e emitir um alerta dizendo faça a conta novamente e se estiver certa parabeniza, e inicia todo processo novamente. Será que podes me ajudar? Incluo aqui o html com as tabelas já ciadas para ficar mais facil.

Segue o codigo do dado que fiz separado para juntar do script maior depois:

```
function executar() {
    document.getElementById(1).innerHTML = rnd(0, 6);
    document.getElementById(2).innerHTML = rnd1(0, 6);
    var res1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('1') value);
    var res2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('2') value);
    /*pelo teste ele não reconhece os valores como numero*/
    alert(eval(res1.value) + eval(res2.value));
    do {

        nome = prompt("Some os valores sorteados Digite o resultado aqui.");

    } while (nome == null || nome == "");

    ok = confirm("Tem certeza que o resultado é " + nome);
    if (ok == 1) {
        setTimeOut("SomarValores();", 3000);

    } else {
        alert("Jogue os dados novamente");
    }

}

function rnd(min, max) {
    var valor = Math.floor(Math.random(parseInt) * max) + 1;
    dadoValor = valor;
    return dadoValor;
    dadoValor = valor;

}

function rnd1(min, max) {
    var valor1 = Math.floor(Math.random(parseInt) * max) + 1;
    dadoValor1 = valor1;
    return dadoValor1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o site do [Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), a função `parseInt();` deveria ser escrita assim:

```
parseInt(String, radix); // em português, base.
```

Então, se você quer `nome` na base 10, teria que escrever assim:

```
parseInt(nome, 10); // nome na base 10.
```

Eu encontrei alguns outros erros de sintaxe, então modifiquei o código para que funcione e seja bem conciso:

```
var numero;
var nomeRes;
var res1;
var res2;

function executar() {

    document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = rnd(0, 6);
    document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = rnd(0, 6);
    res1 = document.getElementById('1').innerHTML;
    res2 = document.getElementById('2').innerHTML;

    nome = prompt("Some os valores sorteados Digite o resultado aqui.");

    numero = parseInt(res1, 10) + parseInt(res2, 10);
    nomeRes = parseInt(nome, 10);

    if (nomeRes == numero) {
        alert("Esta certo!");
    } else {
        alert("Jogue os dados novamente");
    }

}

function rnd(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Eu não sei em qual browser você está testando o seu código, mas no Chrome, você pode apertar `Ctrl + Shift + J` e, na janela que surgir, verificar o valor das variáveis, para saber se elas são nulas, se contém uma `String`, um número, etc.

Eu movi as variáveis para fora da função justamente para poder ter acesso a elas em qualquer momento da execução do programa.

[image: Console Chrome]

Verifique que o valor de `nome` era "4", uma `String` - e o valor de `nomeRes`, já convertido, é um inteiro, 4.

Comment: Valeu mano era isso que eu precisava. Você teria como me ajudar no segundo problema?

Comment: @IsaelT.Costa Talvez! Você já postou ele aqui?

Comment: Ja postei sim, mas não havia postado o código, mas agora ja postei. se puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato

Comment: @IsaelT.Costa Ah, eu não tinha visto que você tinha atualizado a questão. Eu peço uma coisa: Crie uma *segunda pergunta*, com o texto que você escreveu e, se possível, *edite esta* e **reverta** para a original. Isso é importante pois as suas questões podem ajudar futuros visitantes (e, de quebra, você pode obter uma resposta mais rápido!)

Comment: Valeu,obrigado pela orientação